# How to get Dio response

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dio

I am using **dio** by using this I am passing form data and getting response but I am unable to store data to object. Please help me It is giving response when I am printing response.data but I am not getting how to store the response to object.

this my json file [jsonfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAN6v.png)

```
{"datawisata": [
{
  "about": "Sebagai tempat wisata yang menarik dan unik, Wisata Pohon Randu Gede memiliki cerita tersendiri. Konon taman wisata yang satu ini merupakan pohon mistis yang seringkali dijadikan sebagai spot gambar yang kekinian. Karena pohon randu gede sudah ada sejak ribuan tahun lalu dengan ketinggian sekitar 100 meter dan diameter sekitar 20 meter.",
  "alamat": "Jl. Letnan Sutejo, Margadadi, Kec. Indramayu, Kab. Indramayu, Jawa Barat.",
  "hari": "Setiap Hari",
  "id": 1,
  "img": [
    "https://www.javatravel.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Wisata-Pohon-Randu-Gede-1.jpg",
    "https://www.javatravel.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Wisata-Pohon-Randu-Gede-1.jpg"
  ],
  "jam": "24 Jam",
  "kategori": "Wisata Alam",
  "lat": -6.324085360441674,
  "lng": 108.32296841478009,
  "nama": "Pohon Randu Gede",
  "tiket": "Gratis"
},
{
  "about": "Destinasi alam ini selalu ramai setiap akhir pekan dan musim liburan. Lokasinya yang tak jauh dari jantung kota sehingga mudah bagi wisatawan menemukannya. Di sisi lain pesona alam Pantai karangsong memang tidak bisa ditolak keindahannya. Anda akan menemukan keunikan wisata ini, yaitu pantai yang diselimuti hutan mangrov.",
  "alamat": "Jl. Wanasari, Karangsong, Kec. Indramayu, Kabupaten Indramayu, Jawa Barat",
  "hari": "Setiap Hari",
  "id": 2,
  "img": [
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pantai+Karangsong/@-6.3057331,108.3685935,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNx8CI_LcVwFK-CGCTM5c-8ggyzAi3T_q7BjfPt!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNx8CI_LcVwFK-CGCTM5c-8ggyzAi3T_q7BjfPt%3Dw396-h298-k-no!7i4624!8i3472!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!2sPantai+Karangsong!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!10e4!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!14m1!1BCgIgAQ#",
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Pantai+Karangsong/@-6.3057437,108.3686025,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipPxkDxDXcfVdLxDh-GILyccKLwaQSFNbaqodws!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipPxkDxDXcfVdLxDh-GILyccKLwaQSFNbaqodws%3Dw203-h152-k-no!7i4624!8i3468!4m15!1m7!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!2sPantai+Karangsong!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!10e4!3m6!1s0x2e6ebc4872ce9051:0x488988f64087588f!8m2!3d-6.3057331!4d108.3685935!14m1!1BCgIgAQ#"
  ],
  "jam": "08:00 - 17:00 WIB Senin - Jumat\\n07:00 - 18:00 WIB Sabtu & Minggu",
  "kategori": "Wisata Alam",
  "lat": -6.305599800906916,
  "lng": 108.36857204218629,
  "nama": "Pantai Karangsong",
  "tiket": "'1000'"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "nama": "Situs Buyut Banjar",
  "hari": "Setiap Hari",
  "jam": "24 jam",
  "alamat": "Jl. Raya Jatibarang-Karangampel, Bulak, Kec. Jatibarang, Kab. Indramayu, Jawa Barat.",
  "tiket": "Gratis",
  "kategori": "Wisata Kebudayaan",
  "about": "Obyek wisata ini berupa sebuah makam yang dipercaya makam orang pertama yang mendiami Desa Bulak Kidul. Desa ini berlokasi di Kecamatan Jatibarang, Kabupaten Indramayu.\nOrang pertama yang mendiami Desa Bulak dipercaya sebagai utusan salah satu dari Sunan Walisongo. Ada cerita yang selalu melekat pada situs makam ini yaitu tentang keberadaan kera di makam.",
  "lat": -6.4759564813777075,
  "lng": 108.31966886136574,
  "img": [
    "https://www.itrip.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Situs-Buyut-Banjar.jpg",
    "https://www.itrip.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Situs-Buyut-Banjar.jpg"
  ]
},]}
```

this my api file[api file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSkiB.png)

```
class WisataApi {static Future<List<Datawisata>?> getWisata() async {
var result ;
try {
   await Dio().get(
      'https://windramayu-api-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/'); } on DioError catch (e) {
  throw Exception(e.toString());
}
List<Datawisata> _temp = [];
if (result != null) {
  return Datawisata.wisataFromSnapshot(result.data['datawisata']);
}
return _temp;
```

}
}

this my model [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EVaW.png) [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QI8H.png)

```
class Datawisata { String? about; String? alamat;  String? hari; int? id; List<Imgs> img;String? jam;String? kategori;  double? lat;  double? lng;  String? nama;  String? tiket;Datawisata(
  {this.about,
  this.alamat,
  this.hari,
  this.id,
  required this.img,
  this.jam,
  this.kategori,
  this.lat,
  this.lng,
  this.nama,
  this.tiket,}); factory Datawisata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)     return Datawisata( 
about : json['about'],
alamat : json['alamat'],
hari : json['hari'],
id : json['id'],
img : json['img'],
jam : json['jam'],
kategori : json['kategori'],
lat : json['lat'],
lng : json['lng'],
nama : json['nama'],
tiket : json['tiket'],
);} static List<Datawisata> wisataFromSnapshot(List snapshot){
return snapshot.map((data){
  return Datawisata.fromJson(data);
}).toList(); } }class Imgs {  final String img; Imgs({required this.img});  factory Imgs.fromJson(Map<String , dynamic> json)=>Imgs(img: json["img"]!=null?json['img']:'',);  Map<String, dynamic> toJson()=>{    "img": img == null? null: img,  }; }
```

giving response when I am printing response
call the response with provider

```
class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ListWisata> _wisata = [];
  List get wisatalist => _wisata;

  Future<void> getWisatas() async {
    final c = await WisataApi.getWisata();
    _wisata = c!.datawisata!.cast<ListWisata>();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

listwisata[index].datawisata?[index].nama

Answer (score 0):

Change your model class to the following:

```
import 'dart:convert';

DataWisataListModel dataWisataListModelFromJson(String str) => DataWisataListModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataWisataListModelToJson(DataWisataListModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DataWisataListModel {
    DataWisataListModel({
        this.datawisata,
    });

    List<Datawisata> datawisata;

    factory DataWisataListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataWisataListModel(
        datawisata: json["datawisata"] == null ? null : List<Datawisata>.from(json["datawisata"].map((x) => Datawisata.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "datawisata": datawisata == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(datawisata.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datawisata {
    Datawisata({
        this.about,
        this.alamat,
        this.hari,
        this.id,
        this.img,
        this.jam,
        this.kategori,
        this.lat,
        this.lng,
        this.nama,
        this.tiket,
    });

    String about;
    String alamat;
    String hari;
    int id;
    List<String> img;
    String jam;
    String kategori;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    String nama;
    String tiket;

    factory Datawisata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datawisata(
        about: json["about"] == null ? null : json["about"],
        alamat: json["alamat"] == null ? null : json["alamat"],
        hari: json["hari"] == null ? null : json["hari"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        img: json["img"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["img"].map((x) => x)),
        jam: json["jam"] == null ? null : json["jam"],
        kategori: json["kategori"] == null ? null : json["kategori"],
        lat: json["lat"] == null ? null : json["lat"].toDouble(),
        lng: json["lng"] == null ? null : json["lng"].toDouble(),
        nama: json["nama"] == null ? null : json["nama"],
        tiket: json["tiket"] == null ? null : json["tiket"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "about": about == null ? null : about,
        "alamat": alamat == null ? null : alamat,
        "hari": hari == null ? null : hari,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "img": img == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(img.map((x) => x)),
        "jam": jam == null ? null : jam,
        "kategori": kategori == null ? null : kategori,
        "lat": lat == null ? null : lat,
        "lng": lng == null ? null : lng,
        "nama": nama == null ? null : nama,
        "tiket": tiket == null ? null : tiket,
    };
}
```

Change your request function to the following.

```
Future<DataWisataListModel?> getWisata() async {
    Response? result;
    try {
      result = await Dio().get(https://windramayu-api-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/);
      print('getWisata: ${result.data}');
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString());
    }
    if (result != null) {
      return DataWisataListModel.fromJson(result.data);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: n how i can call a data?? provider
like this?
import 'package:windramayu/models/api/wisata_api.dart';
import 'package:windramayu/models/listWisata.dart';


class HomeViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ListWisata> _wisata = [];
  List get wisatalist => _wisata;

  Future<void> getWisatas() async {
    final c = await WisataApi.getWisata();
    _wisata = c!.datawisata!.cast<ListWisata>();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

listwisata[index].datawisata?[index].nama